# Não consigo fazer a aba do chrome fechar sozinha após o Relógio dar o horario determinado no javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let hora = document.getElementById("hora"),
    minuto = document.getElementById("minuto"),
        segundos = document.getElementById("segundos");

        const relogio = setInterval(function time() {
            let dateToday = new Date(),
                hr = dateToday.getHours(),
                    min = dateToday.getMinutes(),
                        seg = dateToday.getSeconds();

            if (hr < 10) hr = `0` + hr;

            if (seg < 10) seg = `0` + seg;

            if (min < 0) min = `0` + min;

    hora.textContent = hr;
    minuto.textContent = min;
    segundos.textContent = seg;
});
```

Comment: Não é permitido a Scripts fechar abas ou fechar janelas abertas pelo usuário. Caso fosse permitido seria aberta uma brecha de segurança onde scripts maliciosos injetados fechariam aleatoriamente o navegador do usuário. Para mais informações veja a documentação [`Window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Answer (score -2):

Para fechar a janela do navegador utilizando `javascript`, você pode adicionar a função `window.close();`. Aqui está como você pode utilizá-lo na prática:

```
if (horario === horarioAlvo) {
    window.close();
}
```

aqui no caso, se meu `horario` for igual a "10:10:10" por exemplo. E `horarioAlvo` tiver o mesmo valor, a janela do navegador será fechada.

Comment: Comentário do AR removido do corpo da pergunta: *"Caso tenha entendido errado a sua pergunta, só me avisar que faço o melhor possível pra te ajudar!"*

Comment: A documentação do método [`Window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) faz uma observação sobre as limitações de uso desse método, que seriam interessante incluir em sua resposta: "...Este método só pode ser chamado em janelas que foram abertas por um script usando o método `Window.open()` ou em janelas de nível superior que possuem uma única entrada de histórico. Se a janela não atender a esses requisitos, um erro semelhante a este aparecerá no console: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script`..."